How can I share state between requests in Django?
This is the first function:
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['uname']
        first_name = request.POST['fname']
        last_name = request.POST['lname']
        email = request.POST['email']
        pass1 = request.POST['pass1']
        pass2 = request.POST['pass2']

This is the second function:
def createPost(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            # To extarct data from web page
            title = form.cleaned_data['title_name']
            description = form.cleaned_data['description']
            print(title)
            # To store Data
            PostData.objects.create(title_name=title, description=description)

How can I get the value of username from first function to second function?

Usually you would do this by saving the current signed-in user in the session.

perhaps signup() might return a instance of a class User() with all those attributes

HTTP was designed to be a stateless protocol but every now and then the need for state is required that is why sessions are used.

Does your signup view actually create a user and log them in? If so your question should be "How to get currently logged in user?" if not your question should be "How do I create a new user?" and "How do I log in a user?" (Note all of these three are very likely duplicates)

When sharing state between requests in HTTP, the standard implementation is to use sessions. Django offers Sessions out of the box. With Sessions you can do this:
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST['uname']
        request.session["username"] = username
        #•••Rest of code•••

def createPost(request):
    username = request.session.get("username")
    if username:
        #•••Do something•••
    #•••Rest of code•••
You probably already have Sessions set up but if you don’t, see the docs [django-docs] to get started.

Uhh, given the name of the first view they'll probably be better off implementing some auth, this current solution might be prone to their users losing access if they ever lose their cookies, etc.

That’s a good call. Session based authentication to be precise and that will need browser cookies. I would still recommend Session over Token authentication. tokens can still be lost.

I don't actually know whether they've implemented auth properly or not but if they have all they need is something like: request.user.username (This uses sessions and cookies behind the scenes, yes). In other terms though their question would then be how to get currently logged in user which would be a duplicate.

From their new question it seems like they actually want the user object.

I see now @AbdulAzizBarkat. I can’t criticize the design because I can’t see it. But I’ll say this: “If the OP implemented Authentication the proper way, these questions won’t be coming up.”
